# Are Thread Input queues global?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

In win32, are thread input queues global to all applications? 
So Application A can attach itself to application B's thread input queue?

Answer (score 1):

[AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956(VS.85).aspx) will do it in fact. A thread in application A can attach itself to the message queue owned by a thread in application B, IF the two processes exist on the same desktop AND process B is not at a higher [integrity level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462.aspx).

Comment: You're confusing "input queues" with "message queues". Each thread has it's own message queue regardless of AttachThreadInput. The AttachThreadInput call will add your thread to a thread group with a common input queue, your thread still retains its own message queue, but shares an input queue.

Answer (score -2):

There's an API that will let you merge your spyware's input queue with the user's banking application.  This kind of thing is gradually getting closed down.

Comment: Sometimes we need to hook into other applications, not just for spyware.